# Why is this CMP instruction failing?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, cmp

I have the following code :

```
CMP BYTE PTR [ESP+5],61    ; ESP is 0012F9AC
JNZ SHORT ....
```

The following is in the memory

```
Address  Data

0012F9AC 0012FA94
0012F9B0 61616161
0012F9B4 61616161
```

Now, the way I understand it is that it is comparing 0x61 to the value at (0x0012F9AC + 5)  which is 0x12F9B1. According to the memory 'dump' the value at address 0x12F9B1 is 0x61. So why is it still insisting on doing the jump ?

Comment: Is it 61 decimal or 61 hexadecimal by the way? If the snippet shown is something you're feeding into the assembler it might be understanding that 61 as decimal thus making the cmp fail

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 0x61. It's from a text input of 'aaaaaaaa', putting in '========' puts in 3D3D3D3D into memory and then it also doesn't jump. Sure I'm missing something simple, I'm still a noob with asm

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not and expert in assembly, but is the ,61 really 0x61?  You could try ,97 as a quick check.

Update: I see blackbear got there first with the same comment.

Answer (score 1):

The stack is DWORD aligned.  Notice your address of the 2 strings, they are a DWORD apart.  What you have are pointers, so of course it is not going to match.

```
[esp] == return address
[esp + 4] == pointer to first string
[esp + 8] == pointer to second string
```

Try this:

```
DoIt:   
    mov     eax, [esp + 4]
    cmp     byte ptr [eax], 061H
    jnz     NotA
    PrintText "a"
    jmp     Over 
NotA:
    PrintText "NOT A"
Over:
    ret 4 * 2
```

Now I can just `inc eax` to get the next character.

Not sure of your context, so I created a test proc, and passed 2 stings to it.

Let's put it this way:  Do you want the box - esp, or do you want what's IN the box [esp]?

Answer (score 0):

The original question quotes this:

```
    Address  Data

    0012F9AC 0012FA94
    0012F9B0 61616161
    0012F9B4 61616161
```

This shows clearly the following points:

1. This is a memory dump, in HEXadecimal.
2. The memory starting at 0012F9B0 is filled by 8 lowercase "a" ansi characters ( 1 byte per character )

The answer given by Gunner is totally bogus for this question. These "a"s are right there, *not* pointers to them !

However, as noted by others, any decent assembler, when they see this line: ...

CMP BYTE PTR [ESP+5],61    ; ESP is 0012F9AC

... they will interpret ",61" above as decimal, so the compare will fail, because 61 decimal is not equal to 61 hexadecimal. THIS is the real reason why the compare will fail.

Just correct like this:

CMP BYTE PTR [ESP+5],61h    ; ESP is 0012F9AC

and the problem is solved.